# how to find dll functions from python?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I'm trying access dll from python with ctypes.
but it could not find functions!
simple code is something like this:

```
from ctypes import cdll
dll=cdll.LoadLibrary("SDK.dll")
SdkService=dll.SDK.Service()
```

and Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Fold1\project\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    SdkService=dll.SDK.Service()
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'SDK' not found
```

now how can i find functions from python?
or any other plan to access functions?

Answer (score 1):

You already loaded the `SDK` dll, there is no need for an additional attribute.

The names exported from `SDK.dll` are attributes of the object returned from `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()` (an instance of the [`CDLL` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL)), which you assigned to the name `dll`.

So if `SDK.dll` exports a function named `Service`, you can call it with:

```
dll.Service()
```

See the [*Accessing functions from loaded dlls* section](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#accessing-functions-from-loaded-dlls) of the `ctypes` documentation.

Take into account that `ctypes.cdll` expects DLLs to use *C function export declarations*. C++ namespaces are not exported.

You may also be dealing with a DLL that uses the Windows-only `stdcall` conventions, at which point you need to use the `ctypes.windll` (assumes functions return `int` by default) or the `ctypes.oledll` (assumes `HRESULT` return values) library loaders. There is no easy way to detect *from the DLL alone* what calling convention it expects. If you have the corresponding `.h` header files (I would expect an SDK to have those), then see if the functions that are defined use `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`. Otherwise, just try to use the DLL with `cdll`, and if you get a `ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (<n> bytes missing) or wrong calling convention` exceptions switch to using `cdll.windll` instead.

Comment: function properties give directory :       Method:SDK.Service.UserInfo(System.String NationalCode,System.Int32 BirthYear)

Comment: @Saeed: the documentation there seem to use C++ namespaces; those are *not part of the exported names*. The name `UserInfo` would be exported, depending on the project configuration. `ctypes` uses the C conventions, not C++ conventions.

Comment: @Saeed: some DLLs export names by ordinal, see the documentation I linked.

Comment: @Saeed: if you are using Windows and have VisualStudio installed, I think you can use `dumpbin /exports SDK.dll` to see what names are exported. Or download the [Dependency Walker utility](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). See [Is there any native DLL export functions viewer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1548637)